# What's the subject in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, subjects, predicate

"Even tap water should be boiled before drinking."

What's the subject and the predicate in this sentence?

Comment: "Tap water" is the subject. What about this sentence confuses you? A more detailed question about the actual problem you have might get you a better answer.

Comment: @gotube Actually, the subject is "even tap water". The focusing adverb "even" modifies "tap water" and hence forms part of the NP subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject is the noun phrase "Even tap water"; the noun is "water", "tap" is an attributive noun functioning as an adjective, and "even" is an intensive adverb modifying the adjective "tap".

Comment: "tap" is not an adjective.

Comment: Right. It's called an attributive noun, and if functions as an adjective. Correction made. See https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-attributive-noun-1689012

Comment: Yes it's a noun but it functions as an attributive modifier of the head.

Comment: Is that different from what I said?

Comment: Definitely. An adjective is a category (parts of speech) but function is different. It is not appropriate or clear to say that a particular word functions as an adjective or a noun. Because it is not clear. An adjective or a noun can function in different ways.